# Sort sql table by sum of values of associated table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
Table 1: Connections
Columns: id, ip, in_bytes, out_bytes, protocol


Table 2: Clients
Columns: id, ip, network
```

I want to list networks sorted by amount of traffic.

I need a query which does the following steps in one request:

1. Find all clients for each network
2. Use ip's from this clients to get all connections for current network
3. SUM traffic (Connections.in_bytes) for all ip's of current network to sort networks by this sum

Can anyone help to create the sql query?

Comment: What database is this, MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, etc etc? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @mituw16 the question is tagged with MySQL

Comment: @Brent, good catch. I missed that one :)

Comment: `Can anyone help to create the sql query?` -- NO. If you have already tried something and stuck somewhere then people here would surely help.

Comment: Lazy - at least try yourself first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple join with a SUM?

```
SELECT a.id, a.ip, a.network, SUM(b.in_bytes + b.out_bytes) AS traffic
FROM Client a
INNER JOIN Connections b
ON a.ip = b.ip
GROUP BY a.id, a.ip, a.network
ORDER BY traffic
```